# create my own memset function in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memset, pointer-arithmetic

here is the prototype:

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n)
```

first im not sure if I have to return something because when I use the memset i do for example

```
memset(str, 'a', 5);
```

instead of

```
str = memset(str, 'a', 5);
```

here is where I am with my code:

```
void *my_memset(void *b, int c, int len)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(b && len > 0)
    {
        b = c;
        b++;
        len--;
    }
    return(b);
}

int main()
{
    char *str;

    str = strdup("hello");
    my_memset(str, 'a', 5);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

I dont want to use array in this function, to better understand pointer and memory, so I dont get 2 things:
- how to copy the int c into a character on my void b pointer
- what condition to use on my while to be sure it stop before a '\0' char

edit: i was wondering is there a way to do this function without casting ?

Comment: You shouldn't love spaces that much buddy..

Comment: `b++` -- this is a problem, considering `b` points to a `void` which has no known size. `b = c;` -- this is a bigger problem that will likely crash your application.

Comment: It should be something like `void ms(char *dst, size_t len, char val) { for (char *p = dst; p != dst + len; ++p) *p = val; }`

Comment: @Maroun I have learn C this way, and now its more clear for me :)

Comment: int is a bad data-type. why not use a known data-type, that reflects the intention (like size_t len; or char c;)

Comment: For educational purposes that's fine, but keep in mind that it's very hard to compete with the performance of intrinsics-based memset/move or even a manual rep stos

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> how to copy the int c into a character on my void b pointer

You convert the void pointer to an unsigned char pointer:

```
void  *my_memset(void *b, int c, int len)
{
  int           i;
  unsigned char *p = b;
  i = 0;
  while(len > 0)
    {
      *p = c;
      p++;
      len--;
    }
  return(b);
}
```

> what condition to use on my while to be sure it stop before a '\0' char

memset have to trust the length that is passed in. memset needs to work on a general piece of memory, not just a 0 terminated string - so there should not be such a check.

If you anyway would need to check for a 0 byte. you'd do

```
if (*p == 0) //or if(!*p )
     break;
```

Comment: Something is going wrong here: The first version had `p = c`, which should be `*p = c`, then @mah edited the answer and removed the assignment completely.

Comment: Where are you setting the contents to c ?

Comment: @MartinR you're correct; I realized that `p = c` was wrong but didn't pay enough attention to find the intention... I thought it was a stray line of code. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: To match C's `memset(s,c,n)`, the `n` parameter is `size_t` and not `int`.

Comment: May I ask why you are defining an unsigned char?

Comment: The `i` is useless and can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic is based on offsetting the pointer by the size of the type it points to. Before you start incrementing that pointer, you should transform it from `void*` to pointer to `char` / `unsigned char`:

```
void* my_memset(void *s, int c, size_t len) {
    unsigned char *dst = s;
    while (len > 0) {
        *dst = (unsigned char) c;
        dst++;
        len--;
    }
    return s;
}
```

also note that [`memset`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) *returns a pointer to the memory area s*, so you should return the original pointer (before you start incrementing it).

Comment: @VivekS From the standard: `The memset function copies the value of c (converted to an unsigned char) into each of the first n characters of the object pointed to by s`. This answer is 100% compatible with the standard's definition of memset.

Comment: @VivekS: The function expects the "byte" and it's perfectly fine if the implementation relies on it since 99% programmers that will use it will pass a valid value instead of trying to find out what will happen if they go against its semantics.

Comment: @Lundin Then why take an int ? You may as well take unsigned char. Also, by the definition above, I am only supposed to pass a char or unsigned char array, because, if I pass a pointer to an integer array, you are going to set n characters to the value c which might not be what the user expected unless he passed 0 for c.

Comment: @VivekS The reason all character handling functions in the C language work on an int rather than char, is because a character could contain the value EOF, which is of type int and has a negative value. However, if you would pass an int containing EOF to memset, you'd likely get garbage as result. In the end, it all boils down to the C standard being generally irrational and insane, then carrying around a lot of weird backwards compatibility crap on top of the insanity.

Comment: @VivekS Indeed you can't pass an integer array, it would cause the program to crash and burn.

Comment: @Lundin, integer array works when we pass 0 which mostly is the case, but isn't there a generic memset which can sort of set char arrays, int arrays etc etc to the value we specify ? Would be good to hear about it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason functions often return a value is to return an error state to the calling function. In memory related functions it's usually the same pointer as where your result should be (including NULL). In your example you might not want to use the return value of your `my_memset` function, but usually it's because it can be included in a code evaluation (can't think of a better word for this), e.g.

```
if(!my_memset((void *)str, 'a', 5))
{
    printf("An error occurred in my_memset()\n");
}
```

or in a macro, e.g. to return pointer to the end of the memory where you copied your `char`:

```
#define INIT_MEM_PTR_END(a,x) (my_memset((void *)&(a), (x), sizeof(a)) + sizeof(a))
```

This is probably not a great example (plus the potential issues if `a` is already a pointer, etc...), but it shows that you can reuse the result without having to write another couple of lines for this to evaluate the result and so on.

You should also check your pointers before dereferencing them. If for example `void *b` is NULL, you'll have a segmentation fault.

Nothing wrong with passing in `void *`, other than the fact that the intention of the function may not be as clear as when passing pointer to a particular data type. Make sure you cast it to something valid though inside. Also this way, the function can be used to set any memory to a particular hex value (through char) or all 0's quite easily.

It would seem like in this case `b` should be cast to the same type as the value you're trying to copy into it, an `int`; however, then the `len` argument becomes unclear, is it size in bytes or number of times `c` should be copied to the `b` pointer?

Since in your `main()` you're copying a `char` into that memory location, then it's just better to change your `c` to a `char`, cast your `b` to a `char*` and make `len` the length in bytes or number of times `c` should be copied to `*b`. Avoid ambiguity.

The way you have written it, it will copy `c` number of times specified by `len` or until you meet the null character, whichever is shortest/soonest. That's fine, if that's your intention.

```
void *my_memset(void *b, char c, int len)
{
    char *b_char = (char *)b;

    if (b == NULL) return NULL;

    while(*b_char && len > 0)
    {
        *b_char = c;
        b_char++;
        len--;
    }

    return b; //as this pointer has not changed
}

int main()
{
    char *str;

    str = strdup("hello");
    if (!my_memset((void *)str, 'a', 5))
    {
        printf("An error occurred in my_memset()\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if *b_char is 0?

Answer (score 1):

```
void   *my_memset(void *b, int c, int len)
{
  if (b == NULL || len <= 0)
      return b;
  unsigned char *ptr = b;
   while(*ptr != '\0' && len--)
    {
      *ptr++ = (unsigned char)c;
    }
  return(b);
}
```

Comment: Argument should not have a type of `char*` and you should not return `b` after being incremented.

Comment: You shouldn't just post code as your answer. Add some explaination to it.

Comment: @LihO I've got the code changed. Did not take that seriously. Just noticed the *b=c for the first glance. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @akluth The others have made quite clear specifications. Nothing special here.

Comment: BTW, this code is almost the most robust and time efficient(do not need to execute the following codes if the b is null or len is negative, although that would also work without errors).(Assembly excluded)

Comment: Why do you check against `\0` in the _target_ destination??? Why do you check against `\0` in the first place? This code makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Lundin Oh, the post said "what condition to use on my while to be sure it stop before a '\0' char"

Comment: To match C's `memset(s,c,n)`, the `n` parameter is `size_t n` and not type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a duff device to have even better performance.

```
#define DUFF_DEVICE_8(aCount, aAction) \
do { \
int count_ = (aCount); \
int times_ = (count_ + 7) >> 3; \
switch (count_ & 7){ \
case 0: do { aAction; \
case 7: aAction; \
case 6: aAction; \
case 5: aAction; \
case 4: aAction; \
case 3: aAction; \
case 2: aAction; \
case 1: aAction; \
} while (--times_ > 0); \
} \
} while (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried one implementation like this:

```
    void memset(void *b, int c, int len)
    {
       char *s = b;

        while(len--)
            *s++ = c;
    }
```